# How do I perform action on selenium which is depends on display results?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

There is a list of search result blocks that I need to perform an action on depending on search results. To simplify this I'll add some sample HTML.

```
<li>
    <div>
        <div> Result1 </div>
        <button> click </button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div> Result2 </div>
        <button> click </button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div> Result3 </div>
        <button> click </button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div> Result4 </div>
        <button> click </button>
    </div>
</li>
```

The results change every time. Suppose I need to perform action on "Result2" then according to my requirement I need to click on the neighboring BUTTON, how can I do this using Java + Selenium?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

The below XPATH expression locates the `<button>` node which is following-sibling to the `<div>` node containing text "Result2"

```
//div[contains(text(),'Result2')]//following-sibling::button
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are going to use this, or something like this, more than once. In that case let's put this code into a reusable method that makes it simple to use.

```
public static void clickResult(String result) {
    new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10))
        .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(MessageFormat.format("//div[./div[text()='' {0} '']]/button", result))))
        .click();
}
```

and then call it like

```
clickResult("Result2");
```

In the method,

1. I've added a wait to make sure that the element is available to be clicked.
2. I'm dynamically building an XPath to find the DIV that contains the passed in string, e.g. "Result2", and then finds the neighboring BUTTON. Be careful of using `contains()` here because depending on how complex the "Result2" string is and what you are searching for, you might end up grabbing the wrong element. If you know that using `contains()` will work fine, you can use the XPath, `"//div[./div[contains(text(),''{0}'')]]/button"`